# How to subtract pandas datetime column from a fixed time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame column with values ranging from 12:00 to 00:00 (Minutes: seconds format) and I am trying to subtract values of that column from a fixed time of 12:00 (Minutes: seconds format). I have created a variable:

```
 twelve_mins = pd.to_datetime('12:00', format='%M:%S')
```

And when I try to create a column "remaining_time", I get the error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'
```

What do I do so that I can find the "remaining_time" value? The column I am subtracting from has been primed to be in datetime form:

```
pbp['time_left_in_period'] = pd.to_datetime(pbp['time_left_in_period'], format='%M:%S').dt.time
```

Here is a toy selection of my data:

```
idx   time_left_in_period
0     00:11:44
1     00:11:44
2     00:11:27
3     00:11:27
4     00:11:23
5     00:11:21
6     00:11:18
7     00:11:02
8     00:10:59
9     00:10:51
10    00:10:51
11    00:10:51
12    00:10:48
13    00:10:48
14    00:10:32
15    00:10:32
16    00:10:21
17    00:10:21
18    00:10:05
19    00:09:56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime.timedelta()

```
pbp['time_left_in_period'] = pbp['time_left_in_period'].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
pbp['remaining_time'] = pbp['time_left_in_period'].apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=12) - x)
```

The result:

```
    time_left_in_period     remaining_time
0       00:11:44                00:00:16
1       00:11:44                00:00:16
2       00:11:27                00:00:33
3       00:11:27                00:00:33
4       00:11:23                00:00:37
5       00:11:21                00:00:39
6       00:11:18                00:00:42
7       00:11:02                00:00:58
8       00:10:59                00:01:01
9       00:10:51                00:01:09
10      00:10:51                00:01:09
11      00:10:51                00:01:09
12      00:10:48                00:01:12
13      00:10:48                00:01:12
14      00:10:32                00:01:28
15      00:10:32                00:01:28
16      00:10:21                00:01:39
17      00:10:21                00:01:39
18      00:10:05                00:01:55
19      00:09:56                00:02:04
```

Comment: Is there any way to apply the df.diff() method to find the duration between remaining time values? So like row 0 would be 00:00:16 (00:00:16-00:00:00), row 1 would be 00:00:00 (00:00:16-00:00:16), row 2 would be 00:00:17 (00:00:33-00:00:16) and so on?

Comment: Maybe set the column as the diff. Like df['remaining_time'] = df['remaining_time'].diff(period=1)